j.l.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'
I'm trying to use @RefreshScope at @Service layer to dynamically change the value of a property.My application successful started, however after make a request then getting this error
j.l.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat o.s.a.t.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)\n\tat o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)\n\tat 
Could someone help me with this issue?
j.l.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

You need to add RefreshScope bean to your @Configuration class:
import org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public RefreshScope refreshScope() {
        return new RefreshScope();
    }
}

